# MS Excel how to convert hours to days with only 8 hour period

Tags: excel

I have an internship with remaining hours of 136:35:00. I want to automatically calculate how many days will I need to consummate the hours in excel but with 8 hours a day period.

I tried using this:

```
=INT((M10)) &" Days " & INT(MOD(M10,INT(M10))*24) & " Hours and " &
MINUTE(A11) & " Minutes"
```

but it gave me a literal 24-hour/day period, hence the output:

```
5 Days 16 Hours and 0 Minutes
```

what am I missing in the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `136:35:00` is in `Cell A1`, try

```
=CEILING(TEXT(A1, "[h]")/8,1)
```

If you're looking for day and hours combination, then try

```
=FLOOR(A1*3,1)&" Days and "&TEXT(SUM(A1,-TIME(8,0,0)*FLOOR(A1*3,1))," h") & " Hours " & MINUTE(A1) & " Minutes "& SECOND(A1) & " Seconds"
```

[image]

If you are not interested in *Seconds*, then use

```
=FLOOR(A1*3,1)&" Days and "&TEXT(SUM(A1,-TIME(8,0,0)*FLOOR(A1*3,1))," h") & " Hours " & MINUTE(A1) & " Minutes "
```

---

***EDIT :***

**FLOOR Function**

*Syntax :* `FLOOR(number, significance)` where `number` is *numeric value you want to round* and `significance` is *multiple to which you want to round*

`FLOOR` function rounds a number down to the nearest multiple of significance.

Now, for example say you have `25:00:00` in `Cell A1` then to break it down to number of days (as your requirement is to calculate number of days based on 8 hours a day), you'll have to use `=FLOOR(A1*24/8,1)` which is same as `=FLOOR(A1*3,1)`. This will give result as `1 day`.

You can also use another simpler formula

```
=INT(A1/"8:00")&" days "&TEXT(MOD(A1/"8:00",1)*8/24,"h"" Hours ""m"" Minutes ""s"" Seconds""")
```

Comment: can you explain the FLOOR(A1*3,1)? I mean how is this calculates the days based on 8-hour period?